# Android: define color using the hue, saturation and brightness

Tags: android, colors, seekbar

I want to calculate color value from the three SeekBar.

I have three seek bar as below:

```
1. Hue SeekBar (0-255)  
2. Saturation SeekBar (0-255)  
3. Brightness SeekBar (0-255)
```

These seek bar have minimum value as 0 and maximum value as 255.
Depending on the change in the seek bar, i want to `Define` and `Calculate` the value of the color, it will change as user change the progress bar.

How to archive this?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v7/graphics/ColorUtils.java

Answer (score -1):

Try using java's [Color.HSBtoRGB()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#HSBtoRGB(float,%20float,%20float)) method

*EDIT*

also android's color has a similar method: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor(float[])